# Why do co-rotating vortices coalesce, but not counter-rotating ones?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, drag, vortex, lift

In studying the aerodynamics of modern aircraft equipped with high-lift devices, I have discovered that quite a number of distinct trailing vortices are present in the immediate wake of an airplane in flight (e.g. off the outboard edge of the flap, the wingtip, etc). However, they always manage to roll-up into a solitary pair of vortices after only a few seconds have elapsed (see below).

[image]

Why do the individual vortex cores in close proximity merge together? This phenomenon appears to occur only when the vortices rotate in the same direction.

Comment: Not enough for a full answer -- consider the pressure field between the vortex pair and the pressure outside of it. You get a Venturi type effect -- the same reason two boats moving side by side get sucked together.

Comment: This clearly cannot be the entire story (if any of it), because counter-rotating vortices do not merge.

Comment: What the heck is going on in that picture?

Comment: @user2357112 A scale model of an airplane moves along a rail in a tunnel. Within the air are dispersed tiny particles which are illuminated by a laser sheet perpendicular to the direction of motion.

Comment: Ah, so the part where it looks like the clouds lash out and crush the airplane is actually the plane moving through the laser sheet and being obscured by the illuminated particles.

Comment: @user2357112 See these videos:
http://youtu.be/HfFfbOdUT0k?t=1m28s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZMcypFErdE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_8tQKVLzE0
http://youtu.be/zW4PmUE151c?t=1m45s

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Intuitive start of an answer:

If you have counter rotating vortices they have zero net angular momentum (to first order). If they merged they would have to have no motion -> where did the energy go. In between the two axes of rotation the fluid moves in the same direction and has no mechanism for dissipation.

By contrast for two vortices with the same direction of rotation the fluids in between travel in opposite directions. They cancel and that leave you with only the vorticity around the outside of the two of them, which makes them merge.

As I said - intuitive start of an answer: I hope someone else can build on it.

Comment: "They cancel and that leave you with only the vorticity around the outside of the two of them, which makes them merge." This is the part that I am looking for a deeper insight into. Helmholtz's theorem can very accurately predict the net vorticity/angular momentum of the merged vortex, but *why* do they come together?

Comment: Also I think that if one vortex is considerably stronger than the other, the larger one can convect the smaller one around itself during the process whereby the two merge.

Comment: I am giving Floris the nod (sadly I can give only one), but Mike definitely gets an assist on this one. Thanks to MSalters as well!!!

Answer (score 11):

Because where they come close together the air in between circulates in such a way as to join them in a single path.

[image]

Floris is right, but maybe this picture helps.

Comment: Any how precisely does that cause one vortex to be subsumed by the other? And what happens if they are of the same strength?

Comment: @BrysonS. Forget subsumption. They simply merge, because each little parcel of air follows a path.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really do need more detail than that. A slightly more rigorous, less hand-waving response on your part would be much appreciated (although your included graphic does nicely illustrate the basic problem).

Comment: @BrysonS. Then check Floris' answer. It's a simple matter of conservation of vorticity (i.e. angular momentum), and kinetic energy.

Comment: If it were that simple, then why not have the two vortices persist, separately and indefinitely? Momentum would be conserved in this instance as well. There must be a deeper principle at work that explains why a system composed of multiple co-rotating vortices is unstable.

Comment: @BrysonS: Well, as I said, when they come close together there will be counter-rotation between them. This will divert flow from each vortex to the other. If you're after a mathematical description of this process, maybe you should research it or better yet, construct it. For the other case, counter-rotating vortices, they don't merge because the physics are obvious, as Floris pointed out.

Comment: I think the process you depicted above with a stagnant region in-between the vortex cores and a sharing of fluid between vortices has considerable promise. I will be thinking carefully about the matter overnight

Comment: Also, look at the area between the two vortices. In Mike's example, there's tremendous shear. The downward motion on the right happens very close to the upward motion on the left. That's not a stable situation. The two currents will interfere, slow each other, become turbulent, and as a result the air there becomes stationary - the core of the new single vortex. In the original question, the flow in the middle is unambiguously downwards and this is a stable pattern.

Comment: @MSalters I believe "viscous shearing" is exactly what the OP is looking for; you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - great picture. I wrote my answer on a phone (hard to make a drawing), and was hoping someone would take it from there. You did.

Comment: So a vortex core has vorticity, but a negligible tangential velocity. The region of collision/shear between the two vortices produces stagnant flow, and this flow serves as the basis for a new, larger core? I think this makes sense, as the new stagnant flow will begin rotating due to viscosity and the rotation of the original cores...

Comment: @BrysonS: Now I'm the one who's skeptical :)  Any vortex has to have a central region of low pressure, so that the pressure gradient provides the radial acceleration keeping it circular, so when the vortices come close together, the pressure gradients have to superimpose, affecting the paths of particles. But the trouble is, if that were the only effect, then counterrotating vortices would also merge. Hmmm...

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey Not necessarily, because we must also consider kinematics as well as dynamics. Sure the cores of counter-rotating vortices may *want* to merge, but they can't because of the wall of fluid moving between them. This would explain why the two final vortices fail to coalesce.

Comment: @BrysonS: I just googled "vortex merging" and a ton of high-quality stuff turned up!

Comment: I am giving Floris the nod (sadly I can give only one), but Mike definitely gets an assist on this one. Thanks to MSalters as well!!!

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey Interestingly, the below paper by Josserand suggests that the circulation of the final vortex is NOT equal to the circulation of the original two vortices. He used DNS simulation quite rigorously, so I have reason to believe his conclusion is correct (although I don't understand it). www.lmm.jussieu.fr/~josseran/papier/merging.pdf

Comment: @BrysonS: It's a great question you asked. In my pilot training, I was taught to be very aware of "wake turbulence" - those invisible vortices coming off heavy-plane wingtips.